# How to use \footskip space when available?

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr, geometry, footer

Consider having multiple page styles (using the `fancyhdr` package) in your document, some of these styles do not have a footer at all. When having multiple page styles how can one use the footskip space when a page style does not have a footer?

## MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
\usepackage[paperwidth=200mm, paperheight=260mm, top=20mm, left=35mm, bottom=20mm, includeheadfoot, showframe]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE Problem]

## Poor Man's Early Answer (if allowed):

I did try using `footskip=0pt` within the page styles without footer and it "works" (a couple of warnings raised by `fancyhdr`). E.g.:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \footskip=0pt
}
```

But I don't know for sure if that is a *fancy* way to do it.

Comment: Personally, I don't think it is good typography to alter the text block like this for certain pages. If this is just for a draft to save trees, well and good.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `\footskip=0pt`use `\enlargethispage{3\baselineskip}`inside `\fancypagestyle{plain}`. This has approx. the same effect but avoids the warning. I used a multiple of `\baselineskip` because generally you want an integral number of `\baselineskip`s in the text height.

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
  \enlargethispage{3\baselineskip}
}
```

[image]